# What are some good drawing programs to use with a ugee m708 on a macbook pro?

Tags: art, digital

i'm just another beginner who wants to get into digital art but got the tablet before anything else.

Comment: This is quite a broad question; people will have different ideas of what a "good" drawing program is, and which one works better with your tablet. Check [ask] if you want to know more.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't ugee. In various web writings it's judged to be well usable for drawing. The tablet costs a fraction of the prices of high end models, so I guess you have no intention to shell out a fortune for programs. In this sense freeware can be recommended. You should learn to work as well with bitmap graphics as with vector, so get 2 programs.

Krita and MyPaint both are for bitmap graphics, Inkscape is for Vectors. For bitmap graphics there's also GIMP, but it'svery complex, It's plus is a big selection of available tutorials. The same can be said of Inkscape.

There are also several web based free services for vector and bitmap drawing. They are of course free only to some point, they cannot stay alive without money, so to get all available capablities  you must subscribe. They offer a possibility to start without installing anything.

I guess a majority of us have Adobe's programs. They have been around very long time and they cost some real money, so their development at least have a possibility to be well managed. It shows as quite coherent user interface and properties that professional users want. I guess it's a good idea to run at least the trial after you have gained some familiarity with free software.